# Generating a 60 Hz square wave to control a thin-film polarizing film with decent efficiency

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, h-bridge

I recently was tasked with researching and designing a power circuit that takes in 24 VDC (from a 300 Watt PS off mains (120 VAC sine)) and outputs a minimum of 400 mA at 100 VAC, 60 Hz square wave. My approach to boost the power was to use an [LT8361](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt8361.pdf).

To make the DC voltage to square wave AC I chose to use an H-bridge with MOSFETs (SI3437DV-T1-E3 and SI3440ADV-T1-GE3) where the gates are modulated by a PNP BJT (2SC2881-YTE12L,ZC) whose base is controlled with a micro-controller.

I do not need the square wave to be super clean, but I do need it to be AC from +100 V to -100 V. The purpose of the circuit is to control a thin-film polarizing film which is just a resistive load (non-inductive).

[image: H-Bridge in mind]

Is my approach bad in terms of efficiency?

Comment: Right off the bat I see you are busting the Vgs(max) ratings of both the PFETs and NFETs (+/- 20V for each) but even if you weren't the 24ms RC time constant of the gate capacitances with the 40k pull-ups means that shoot-through will destroy your transistors within a few cycles.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I thought I was in the clear since Vds was 150V. Are you informed enough on the subject matter(power electronics) to  tell me if my method of using H-Bridge is correct or should i look at already available IC. Or am i on the right track but need to learn more about MOSFET?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn’t consider using a power transformer? Is size/weight a consideration?  It would mean you could use a handful of cheap and common parts to achieve your goal.

Comment: The biggest reason for going with LT8361 is Size/ weight consideration. The 24VDC is obtained from a 300Watt power supply takes in 120VAC sine and outputs 24VDC so I just needed to boost it and invert it for the specific load because most of the power is used on separate electronics.

Answer (score 2):

> Is my approach bad in terms of efficiency.

Well, boosting 24V to 100V and supplying this 100V to a H-bridge to have ±100V across the load can be a way to go, but would be more meaningful if your application requires 100 VDC somewhere else in the system. Otherwise it's a tad overkill.

Driving a 1:4.2 transformer with an H-bridge could be an option:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdlprG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> should i look at already available IC.

The ICs shown in my principal schematic above are half-bridge drivers (a.k.a. bootstrap drivers) which might be worth considering as they allow you to use N-Ch MOSFETs for both high- and low-side so you can save space and maybe a few pence. Also some insert fixed or programmable dead-time to prevent shoot through which can be destructive. I can't give a part number here but they are one google away.

**NOTE:** I put a 12V linear regulator for the HB driver ICs, but doesn't have to be 12V. Most of today's common HB driver ICs accept supplies up to 20V. Also the decoupling caps and any other components are not shown to keep the schematic as simple as possible.

Comment: @greybeard not generally. Today's most of common HB gate drive ICs do not have supply voltages higher than 20V. Of course there are ones rated for higher than 28-30V but not that common, or they are for specific applications, and also expensive.